# Error con blogdown en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Hola a todos ¿Cómo están?

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en blogdown y me estoy guiando con base a este libro https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-deploy.html , en los primeros pasos funciono todo bien pero para intentar agregar un nuevo post, me genera el siguiente error (adjunto imagen con el error) :

```
> blogdown:::new_post_addin()
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4767
Warning: Error in : 'alnum_id' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'
  54: blogdown:::dash_filename
  53:  ::
shiny
observe
  52: <observer>
   9: shiny::runApp
   8: shiny::runGadget
   7: eval
   6: eval
   5: sys.source
   2: source_addin
   1: blogdown:::new_post_addin
```

[[image: Error en blogdown1]

En el libro que les comente indica que estos errores suceden cuando no tienes instalado shiny, pero si lo he instalado y lo he actualizado, y la verdad es que no se a que se deba, si alguien ha pasado por esto y lo pudo resolver, que me pueda ayudar indicándome o señalando que debo corregir o instalar para poder continuar con blogdown, les agradecería mucho.

Saludo y de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En general, este tipo de problemas son bastaste complejos, porque tienen que ver con como están instaladas las dependencias, versiones y paths de instalación de los paquetes. Me ha ocurrido un montón de veces este mismo tipo de errores, no particularmente con bookdown, pero sí con otras herramientas de rstudio. Estas son las soluciones que propongo para tu problema. De la más simple a la más compleja.

### Solución 1

Actualizar tus librerias. Estuve leyendo que la función alnum_id se creo hace poco.

```
update.packages()
```

Si tienes poco tiempo, actualiza lo que podría estar relacionado:

```
update.packages(c("xfun","rmarkdown","shiny","bookdown"))
```

### Solución 2

Reinstala los paquetes en cuestión:

```
install.packages(c("xfun","rmarkdown","shiny","bookdown"),dependencies=T)
```

Con "dependencies=T", instalas no solo las dependencias necesarias para el funcionamiento correcto, sino que para funcionar de la manera más optima.

### Solución 3

Desinstalar R y RStudio y volver a instalarlos. Se que suena tedioso, pero a veces es la forma más rápida de resolver el problema.

Si nada de esto funciona, te sugiero que envíes una consulta directamente en el [foro de RStudio](https://community.rstudio.com/t/welcome-to-the-rstudio-community/8). Creo que sería útil en esta instancia compartir la información de tu sesión de cuando se produce el error. Eso se hace utilizando el siguiente comando, después de que se genera el error

```
sessionInfo()
```

Espero que te ayude. Saludos.